# IIS: Multi level subdomain with wildcard not resolving

Tags: iis, subdomain, iis-10

Let's say I have a website - example.com. If I create a binding in IIS, with *.example.com then abc.example.com works.

However, abc.in.example.com doesn't work. It gives me 404 status code.

Any suggestions.

Comment: Is: "Learn how wildcards work" a valid answer for you? Because you expect things to work that are explicitly not working by standards.

Comment: @TomTom Not sure. If one only knew how it worked, there wouldn't be this question.

Comment: Yeah, but rtfm is not really optional. It is clear in any documentation i ever read that wildcards are ONE LEVEL ONLY and do not extend downwards.

Comment: @TomTom I've seen u b4 (u r an SO legend), and I appreciate that you ARE answering the OP's Question v. clearly (thanks, helped me)... but if we all read the manuals for everything we used, all the time... we'd never get anything done. e.g. did you miss this one https://serverfault.com/conduct "Engaging with users
No matter where you engage on the network with your peers, we expect all users to treat one another with kindness and respect." This guy has 131 points...

Comment: "but if we all read the manuals for everything we used, all the time... we'd never get anything done" - and STILL it is a requirement on this site, as per site rules. Best practices. Also, your competence or lack thereof is not something I have seen in top people I hired - they generally read the manual. Also think of the future - if you are not even able to read the manuals, what you think happens in 3-5 years when AI HAS read all the manuals? Here is the result: you are one of the first fired. And again, RTM is not optional AS PER THE RULES OF THIS SITE, so - stop being entitled.

Comment: ...your aggression IS something I have seen in people I have ...fired. I thanked you, complimented you, but dared to disagree... and I am "entitled". You are breaking the site rules, aggression at the OP, now me... so maybe you should RT*M? or maybe learn to meditate/chill out.

Comment: Oh and AI read everything on Google books a LONG time ago...

Comment: "we expect all users to treat one another with kindness and respect"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how wildcard certificates work. `*.example.com` work only for hosts like: `host1.example.com`, `host2.example.com`, etc.

If you want to have it work for `abc.in.example.com` you need to use certificate for `*.in.example.com`

The same is situation with binding to wildcard hosts.

Comment: Thanks @RomeoNinov for your answer. That worked for me.

Comment: @Tushar, if you are happy with my answer feel free to accept it (tick on the left side of the answer) :)